# A Question about orthocenter and tangents to circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

#### Problem

[image]

The altitudes $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$ of $\Delta ABC$ meet at the orthocenter $H$.

Since $\angle AEH=\angle AFH=90^\circ$, $AEHF$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Let $U$ and $V$ be points lying on the circle $AEHF$ such that $BU$ and $CV$ are the tangents to the circle $AEHF$ at $U$ and $V$ respectively.

Since $\angle BEC=\angle BFC=90^\circ$, $BCEF$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Let $W$ be the intersection point of the circle $BCEF$ and the line segment $AH$.

Prove that $BU=BW$ and $CV=CW$.

#### My Progress

Since $\angle CDH=\angle CEH=90^\circ$, $CDHE$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Considering the power of point with respect to circles $AEHF$ and $CDHE$, we have $BU^2=BE\cdot BH=BC\cdot BD$.

Since $\angle BDH=\angle BFH=90^\circ$, $BDHF$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Considering the power of point with respect to circles $AEHF$ and $BDHF$, we have $CV^2=CF\cdot CH=BC\cdot CD$.

Hence, we have $BU^2+CV^2=BC\cdot BD+BC\cdot CD=BC\cdot (BD+CD)=BC^2$

Since $BC$ is a diameter of the circle $BCEF$, we have $BW^2+CW^2=BC^2$.

Hence, any one of the equalities $BU=BW$ and $CV=CW$ implies the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's investigate the length of $WD$.
[image]

We know that:

$$AF.AB=AW.AM=AW.(AW+WM)=AW.(AW+2WD)\\=(AD-WD)(AD-WD+2DW)=AD^2-WD^2 \\ \implies WD^2=AD^2-AF.AB.$$
Now, note that:

$$BW^2=BD^2+WD^2=BD^2+AD^2-AF.AB=AB^2-AF.AB \\=BF.AB=BU^2.$$

We are done.